# Case insensitive argparse choices

Tags: python, argparse, case-insensitive

Is it possible to check [argparse choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices) in case-insensitive manner?

```
import argparse
choices = ["win64", "win32"]
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", choices=choices)
print(parser.parse_args(["-p", "Win32"]))
```

results in:

```
usage: choices.py [-h] [-p {win64,win32}]
choices.py: error: argument -p: invalid choice: 'Win32' (choose from 'win64','win32')
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Transform the argument into lowercase by using

```
type = str.lower
```

for the `-p` switch.

This solution was pointed out by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616778/case-insensitive-argparse-choices#comment43678050_27616814). The solution I proposed earlier was

```
type = lambda s : s.lower()
```

which is also valid, but it's simpler to just use `str.lower`.

Comment: You can get rid of the lambda by simply using `type = str.lower`, since `str.lower` is a function that takes a string and returns it in lower case.

Comment: Since the [string.lower(s)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower) _function_ was deprecated and replaced with the [s.lower()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) _method_, I would recommend the lambda approach as originally suggested.

Comment: @Mark Neither version uses the deprecated function from the `string` module. Note that `str.lower` (without `ing`) is used, which is the method from the `str` class taking `self` as its only parameter which is why the trick works.

Comment: @5gon12eder Thanks for the heads up, that makes sense! Good to know. @chepner's description threw me off because he said that this is the str.lower _function_ which "takes a string" which would imply he was referring to the now deprecated _function_ rather than the replacing _method_ that doesn't take any input, but acts on `self`.

Comment: `obj.method(*args, **kwargs)` is for the most part identical to `type(obj).method(obj, *args, **kwargs)`. `str.lower` should rightly be called a function because none of its arguments are bound, whereas `obj.lower` is a method because `obj` is bound as the first argument.

Answer (score 20):

Using `lower` in the `type` is nice way of doing this, if you don't mind loosing the case information.

If you want to retain the case, you could define a custom `choices` class.  The `choices` needs two methods, `__contains__` (for testing `in`), and iteration (to list the choices).

```
class mylist(list):
    # list subclass that uses lower() when testing for 'in'
    def __contains__(self, other):
        return super(mylist,self).__contains__(other.lower())
choices=mylist(['win64','win32'])
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", choices=choices)
print(parser.parse_args(["-p", "Win32"]))
# Namespace(p='Win32')
```

The help is:

```
usage: ipython [-h] [-p {win64,win32}]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
  -p {win64,win32}
```

Comment: Just to be safe, I'd probably do `choices = mylist(map(str.lower, ['win64', 'win32']))`, or override `__init__` to do this.

Answer (score 10):

To clarify @5gon12eder's answer, you need to include the "type" as another paramater to `add_argument`:

```py
parser.add_argument("-p", choices=choices, type=str.lower)
```

This will make sure that the input is lowercased.
Make sure to NOT add parentheses after `lower`.

Answer (score 5):

Keeping the case information would also be possible with a one liner:

```
type = lambda arg: {x.lower(): x for x in choices}[arg.lower()],
```

Where choices would be the same list as passed to the choices parameter.