# How to accept `choices` in Python argparse irrespective of case?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a flag in a Python program which can only be certain strings, `rock`, `paper`, or `scissors`. Python argparse has a great way to implement this, using `choices`, container of the allowable values for the argument.

Here's an example from the documentation:

```
import argparse
...
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='game.py')
parser.add_argument('move', choices=['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
parser.parse_args(['rock'])
### Namespace(move='rock')
parser.parse_args(['fire'])
### usage: game.py [-h] {rock,paper,scissors}
### game.py: error: argument move: invalid choice: 'fire' (choose from 'rock','paper', 'scissors')
```

I would like to implement `choices` such that the choices are not case-sensitive, i.e. users could input `RoCK` and it would still be valid.

What is the standard way to do this?

Comment: try `sys.argv`  and can access them by index/order of arguments

Comment: can you do `parser.parse_args(['rock'.lower()])` ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set `type=str.lower`.

See [Case insensitive argparse choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616778/case-insensitive-argparse-choices)

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='game.py')
parser.add_argument('move', choices=['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'], type=str.lower)
parser.parse_args(['rOCk'])
# Namespace(move='rock')
```