# Case insensitive argparse choices without losing case information in choices list

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, ignore-case

I have a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27616778/10027628) but the solutions provided do not fit, since I have a slightly different use case.
For the sake of simplicity I'll adapt my question to the one already answered.

Is it possible to check [argparse choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices) in case-insensitive manner, without losing the case-sensitive information?

```
import argparse
choices = ["ADASYN", "BorderlineSMOTE", "KMeansSMOTE"]
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", choices=choices)
print(parser.parse_args(["-p", "adasyn"]))
```

this leads to:

```
choices.py: error: argument -p: invalid choice: 'adasyn' (choose from 'ADASYN', 'BorderlineSMOTE', 'KMeansSMOTE')
```

I obviously could use *type.lower*, but then my list of choices needs to be in lower case and I lose a lot of readability for -h (help output). On the other hand I want my user to be able to use different casing as long as the string .lower() for both is the same.

The [solution provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27628376/10027628) by @hpaulj (similar question) does not work in my case. It only enables the argument input to have arbitrary casing. So if my choices list is lowercase *AdAsyN* would work, but if I keep the choices list in CamelCase, the uppercase letters in the choices list have to be uppercase for the argument as well.

Does anyone have a solution for me, where I can keep the casing of my choices list, while completely ignoring casing for the user input?

Comment: The link shows to tools - customize the `type` function, and customize the `choices` object.  Argparse is doing a simple `in` test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize type function to perform search in *choices* list instead simple type conversion. This looks a little bit hackish but works OK.

```
def make_type(choices):
    def find_choice(choice):
        for key, item in enumerate([choice.lower() for choice in choices]):
            if choice.lower() == item:
                return choices[key]
        else:
            return choice
    return find_choice

choices = ["ADASYN", "BorderlineSMOTE", "KMeansSMOTE"]    
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", choices=choices, type=make_type(choices))


print(parser.parse_args("-p adasyn".split()))
# Namespace(p='ADASYN')

print(parser.parse_args("-p ADASYN".split()))
# Namespace(p='ADASYN')

print(parser.parse_args("-p aDaSyN".split()))
# Namespace(p='ADASYN')

print(parser.parse_args("-p adasyn1".split()))
# usage: argsaction.py [-h] [-p {ADASYN,BorderlineSMOTE,KMeansSMOTE}]
# argsaction.py: error: argument -p: invalid choice: 'adasyn1' (choose from 'ADASYN', 'BorderlineSMOTE', 'KMeansSMOTE')
```

Closure function taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8632404/446792).
Answer based on @hpaulj comment.